# CustomID in the new PayPal mobile SDK

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

Is it possible to pass a custom ID to the new PayPal mobile SDK?

We need to use the custom ID in order to use the IPN message service. Without the custom ID, IPN becomes useless.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there is no support for you to pass a custom ID to the new PayPal mobile SDK.  There are several use cases for this which are being discussed within PayPal.

PayPal will likely support webhooks for SDK payments at some time in the future, but no specific announcements about this have been made yet.  Not sure exactly what you are trying to do, but maybe there are alternatives to using IPNs.